# Facebook PHP getLogoutUrl not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK.
I try to getLogoutUrl.
I've got **https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=URL&access_token=0** but when I click this url, I always go to **https://www.facebook.com/home.php**

I've tried this(['getLogoutUrl' Does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229869/getlogouturl-does-not-work)) but not work.

That is my code

```php
$config = array(
    'appId' => '<APP ID>',
    'secret' => '<APP Secret>',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email,user_groups',
    'display' => 'page'
));
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

Comment: So what's the question? what do you want the `logOut` URL to be? it's impossible to change the `logout` URL ..

Comment: I want the URL to logout Facebook URL from PHP SDK.

Comment: If you never have the user navigate to the `$loginUrl` then there will never be an access_token (or cookie), which will cause `getLogoutUrl()` to redirect to the Facebook home, instead of back to your app.